# Issue in table creation using bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to generate a table using bootstrap grid system. Below html code I have created to generate table but it is not working properly as the table cells are getting overlapped for a 768px screen size.

```css
.row.header {
  height: 44px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
p.block-space {
  margin: 15px 0 16px 0px;
}
div[class^="col"] > label {
  margin: 15px 0 16px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 14px Helvetica;
  color: #666666;
}
.col-margin-header {
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}
.col-margin {
  margin-left: 15px !important;
}
.xs-col-margin {
  margin-left: 5px !important;
}
dt.heading {
  font: bold 14px Helvetica;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
}
.dd-description {
  font: normal 14px Helvetica;
  color: #666666;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  div[class^="col"] {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  .row {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  div[class^="col"] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .row {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
}
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  div[class^="col"] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .row {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
}
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  /*default so you don't need this*/
  div[class^="col"] {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .row {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Grid System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="row header visible-sm-block visible-md-block">
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
        <label class="col-margin-header">Select</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-11">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Bank</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Division</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Department</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Bank</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Agent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Company</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Division</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <label>Department</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
        <p class="block-space col-margin visible-sm-block visible-md-block">
          <input type="radio" />
        </p>
        <p class="block-space xs-col-margin visible-xs-block">
          <input type="radio" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Bank</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Agent</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Company</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Division</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Department</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Bank</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Agent</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Company</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Division</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
          <dl class="visible-xs-block"><dt class="heading">Department</dt>
            <dd class="dd-description">Description goes here</dd>
          </dl>
          <p class="visible-sm-block visible-md-block">Description goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this code is workign fine on the desktop the problem is with a 768px screen size.

Comment: "Not working properly" is a meaningless statement. What is the *expected* behaviour, and what do you *get instead*?

Comment: Instead of creating div base table, try to use [Datatable.js](https://www.datatables.net/examples/index) for better output and responsiveness.

Comment: Not working means table cells are getting overlapped.

Comment: why don't you use a table for a table

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you using the divs for the layout as tables in Bootstrap are notoriously painful. However, I think the reason it's overlapping because the cells are simply too small for the content.

You therefore have a couple of options:

The first is to add "overflow:hidden;" to the columns which will hide the extra content, but stop it overlapping:

```
div[class^="col"] {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4sxogckb/

But this is kind of pointless as you can't read the data.

Next, you can force the long words to break:

```
div[class^="col"] {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8swd3km5/

However this is rather ugly.

Finally, your best solution is to revisit the design and try and come up with a way of presenting the data that doesn't displaying an 11-column table on smaller-screened devices.